# sequelize vs sql stored procedure. What should I be using in my case?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for calculating my dashboard numbers. There are more than 5000 users right now and this number intends to grow. For each user I have to process a lot of data with lots of conditions/rules and with multiple joins.

for around 250 test users sequelize takes more than 25 seconds to return the result. Should I switch to stored procedures to make performance better or is there a way to optimize sequelize queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, we need to see some of your model and their associations.
But, you must try first to optimize your models because sequelize doesn't create index, but you can create your own ´Foreign key´, for example:

```
MyModel.hasMany(models.MyModel2, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
MyModel.hasMany(models.MyModelX, {foreignKeyConstraint: true});
```

Also, sequelize slows down in segregate operations or numeric operations (like ´AVG´), and is better option if you don't include them into your largest queries.

In my personal case (maybe is not the better approach), for big number of records, I prefer to `stored procdures` and generate my own index to execute biggest queries with better performance.

Also, as you know node.js is single thread, then you must optimize the operations in your server side.

In conclusion, if you're using segregate operations or mathematic opeations in the query, my recomendation is "use stored procedures".